# Get Position of a Term and the document the positions belong to

Tags: java, lucene

I have just started with Lucene and got stuck somewhere in the middle.

I can get the positions of the search terms using the code snippet from [How to get positions from a document term vector in Lucene?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35809035/3064513)[here])

And the Document path or Id from this code

Indexing:

```
String path = file.getCanonicalPath();
document.add(new StringField(FIELD_PATH, path, Field.Store.YES));
```

Searching:

```
Document document = indexSearcher.doc(scoreDoc.doc);
String path = document.get(FIELD_PATH);
```

How can i combine these two to get the Path or Document Id AND the term positions of that corresponding document

There are similar questions but most the questions regarding positions on this site or on the internet are pretty old and the corresponding classes are deprecated.

Comment: You could do this by fetching position vectors directly, yes.  But are you trying to highlight search results or something similar?  If so, the [Highlighter API](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/highlighter/org/apache/lucene/search/highlight/Highlighter.html) is probably the easier solution.

Comment: No, i don't want to highlight. I only need position of search terms and their documents and i googled _position vectors_  didn't find anything useful/non-deprecated can you help me here?

Comment: To iterate terms in a field, the typical entry point would be [IndexReader.getTermVector](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#getTermVector(int,%20java.lang.String)).  Use [TermsEnum.SeekExact](http://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/TermsEnum.html#seekExact(org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRef)) to find the desired term in the enumeration.

Comment: IndexReader,getTermVector only has my positions terms and not the document Id(or Path). Should I explain more of my code here? I believe this will turn out to be more of a XY problem .... Maybe a simple code snippet for position and StringField together for lucene 5.4 might help

Comment: You get the DocID from the `ScoreDoc`, and stored field values from the `Document`, just as your current search code already shows.  You then pass the `DocID` retrieved into the `getTermVectors` which you can use to iterate the term vector enumeration, which contains the positions.