# What is wrong with my Lucene code?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have an array of searchable terms, and I want to use Lucene to basically CTRL-F through this stack of documents and find and store the locations of all of those terms within that stack of documents. For example:

Terms: "A", "B", "C"

Doc1: "CREATION"
Doc2: "A BIG CAR"
Doc3: "DOUBLE TROUBLE"

If I query the letter "A", I want to be able to say that there are 3 "A"s:

- Doc1 at position 4
- Doc2 at position 1
- Doc2 at position 8

Something like that. How can I do this? So far, I'm just using a StandardAnalyzer like so:

```
public Analyzer _analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);

// for some directory defined here

using (var indexWriter = new IndexWriter(directory, _analyzer, true, new IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength(IndexWriter.DEFAULT_MAX_FIELD_LENGTH)))
{
    using (var textReader = new StreamReader(blobStream))
    {
        // this code should analyze and write my indexes to the lucene instance

        var text = await textReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        var document = new Document();
        document.Add(new Field("Text", text, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.WITH_POSITIONS_OFFSETS));
        document.Add(new Field("DocId", docId.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        document.Add(new Field("FamilyId", familyId.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
        indexWriter.AddDocument(document);
    }
}
```

Lucene originally generates a lot of documents, but then deletes all but the .cfs file. How do I keep the other files to do my queries?

Answer (score 0):

To index on arbitrary char positions, you can use the [NGramTokenizer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/ngram/NGramTokenizer.html). While creatiung the Index, you should also use `FieldType.setStoreTermVectors(true);` and `FieldType.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);` so that the positions of the terms are actually stored. Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35809035/how-to-get-positions-from-a-document-term-vector-in-lucene) that has the correct code for retrieving the term positions already in the question.

Comment: How does `FieldType` fit into my code? Is `FieldType` a property of `Field`? I don't get it. The example just shows `FieldType` as a floating thing. I have no idea how it relates to the `Document` object, the `Analyzer ` object, or the `IndexReader` object.

Comment: I just realized that you may use Lucene major version 3? Is this correct? If so, please update to something reasonable (at least 5, better 6).

Comment: Yes, I'm using Lucene.NET 3.0.3. My boss is a big .NET fan.Don't know if the .NET version is caught up to the java version. Is it that different?

Comment: Well, the release note of Lucene.NET 3.0.3 dates back to `Friday October 26, 2012`. This stuff is outdated as heck. There seems to be at least a 4.8-ish version available (http://code972.com/blog/2016/07/98-lucene-net-4-8-is-in-beta-and-we-need-your-help) but that is still way behind the original Lucene which is in version 6.4.2 (with major versions 4 and 5 having brought major changes and updates as well).